# How to use custom values to get keycode?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For example: I have this line of code:

```
private string customKey = "A";
```

And I would like to get `Keycode.A` by using `customKey`,  and`Keycode.customKey`won't work. Could someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/653106/string-to-keycode.html), you can use `Enum.Parse`:

```
    private string key = "A";
    private KeyCode customKeyCode;

    private void Start()
    {
        customKeyCode = (KeyCode) System.Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), key);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(customKeyCode))
        {
            print(key);
        }
    }
```